# Sql queries - select all or multiple small queries

Tags: php, sql

I have been running into hosting issues lately with CPU usage being too high resulting in the host disabling the website (its free hosting, im poor :P) . I programmed the site myself in PHP and is a blog style site. The host has suggested trying to reduce SQL calls. For the home page of my site there are 3 sql queries made to the same table to obtain 7 specific rows each time. The table is for blog posts so as of now it contains around 100 posts but needs to eventually handle having a lot more.

Is it more efficient to do a SELECT * when the page loads then use php to find the specific rows i want or is 3 small SQL queries more efficient?

Comment: If you're making the same queries repeatedly, have you looked into caching, e.g. memcached?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the details of the query. Also, there may be ways to optimize your queries -- perhaps you don't have appropriate indexes to speed it up. With only 100 posts, there's probably not much difference between any technique, it will only matter when your database grows.

Comment: Why would you need "3 small SQL queries" to replace a `select *`?  Wouldn't a `where` clause and column selection be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use * to return all columns in a table. You should only extract the data you need. Even if you require every field, your tables will inevitably change.

If you want to save a certain number of rows for use throughout a page, instead of calling over and over again, could you save the output in an array (or other structure) and reference that each time instead of grabbing the data in 3 separate calls?

Hope I'm understanding your question.

Also, try this link to read about db call speeds: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/23/speeding-up-your-websites-database/